# htaccess has allow origin yet still shows cors error

Tags: .htaccess, cors

I have this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# To force CN to use https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jobs.connectnigeria\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://jobs.connectnigeria.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# dont rewrite if there was posted here!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)">
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>

#User-agent: *
#Disallow: /

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php54” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php54 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

As you can see, I have this

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

but still showing me this error

[image]

any help, ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

`cnmain.connectnigeria.com` should set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for the font to either `*` or `jobs.connectnigeria.com`. You are doing it on `jobs.connectnigeria.com`.

Comment: tried this to cnmain.connectnigeria.com <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule> but seems not working, it returns me an internal server error

Comment: @JuliverGalleto Cannot predict what is wrong without getting the inner exception details